# How do I create a report on user's email addresses in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

I have a website. To track the mail address of my users on Google Analytics I include the following script:

```
_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar',
     1,                   // Slot #1
     'email',             // Variable name
     'email@example.com', // Variable value
     1                    // Scope = visitor-level, optional
]);
```

I'm not a frequent user of Google Analytics.

How can I see the individual email address of users in the GA web tool (no premium account)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a report for your custom variables under *Audience*→*Custom variables*:
[image: Custom variables menu item]

From here, click *Customize*:

[image: Customize menu item]

Under *Dimension drilldown*, you should be able to find your custom variables in the list:

[image: Custom variables]